# highcharts shows the axis but not the graph plot

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

hey am new to highcharts and was working with an example but it did not work, it shows the axis but not the line graph. it would be so much helpful if anyone could provide me resources to work with highchart using dotnet.
       //defining axis

```
  hcLine.YAxis.Add(new YAxisItem { title = new Title("values") });
  hcLine.XAxis.Add(new XAxisItem { categories = new[] { "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999" } });

  //new data collection
  var series=new List<Serie>();
  series.Add(new Serie{data=new object[]{400,450,500,550,600,660}});

  //bind
  hcLine.DataSource=series;
  hcLine.DataBind();
```

Comment: Do you use any wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can find all the documentation from the following link:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts